# how to take multiple inputs from user using for loop in python?

Tags: python, python-3.x, list

I am making a basic program in which I want to store multiple inputs from the user in the predefined list. 
My approach

```
exampleList = []
exampleList = input("Enter the choice of user1: ")
exampleList = input("Enter the choice of user2: ")
exampleList = input("Enter the choice of user3: ")
exampleList = input("Enter the choice of user4: ")
exampleList = input("Enter the choice of user5: ")
# I want to store 5 number inputs in examples list
```

But I don't want to use input function multiple times.
Desired Output:

```
exampleList = [2,3,5,4,1]
```

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You could store all of these inputs in a list called `inputs` using the following:

```
inputs = list()                                                         

for idx in range(1, 5): 
    inputs.append(input(f"Enter the choice of user {idx}: "))
```

Test time using `ipython`:

```
In [0]: inputs = list()                                                         
   ...: for idx in range(1, 6):  
   ...:     inputs.append(input(f"Enter the choice of user {idx}: ")) 

Enter the choice of user 1: 12
Enter the choice of user 2: 1234
Enter the choice of user 3: 54326
Enter the choice of user 4: 3232
Enter the choice of user 5: 55 

In [1]: print(inputs)                                                           
['12', '1234', '54326', '3232', '55']
```

Comment: Thank you, Sir. I am new to programming so I am learning some basics of it.

Comment: My pleasure. If that suits your needs, you may "accept" the answer.

Answer (score 1):

You can also try using list Comprehension ,it is most elegant way to define and create a list.

```
>>>a=[input("enter choice of user%d : "%(i+1)) for i in range(5)]
enter choice of user1 : 2
enter choice of user2 : 3
enter choice of user3 : 4
enter choice of user4 : 5
enter choice of user5 : 1
>>>print(a)
[2,3,4,5,1]
```